# Sort input to mapper Hadoop streaming

Tags: python, sorting, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I am using Hadoop Streaming 2.7.3 with Python. Is there a way in which I can sort the data **after it has already been distributed to the mappers but before the mapper starts processing it**?

I have tried using UNIX sort command piped with my mapper.py file and gave it as the "mapper" option in hadoop streaming, but it doesn't work. Something like

```
-mapper "sort -t' ' -k2,2n | python3 mapper.py"
```

I have also tried using the UNIX sort command as the mapper and the mapper.py file as the combiner but to no avail. Like

```
-mapper "sort -t' ' -k2,2n"
-combiner "python3 mapper.py"
```

Comment: I dont think there is a way. A mapper is only given one key/value at a time, so your sort won't do anything. You would need to run another MR job prior to this one if you want some sort of ordering before it hits the mapper.

Comment: As far as I know  I do not think that is possible. Hadoop do 3 type of sorting which are
 1) Sorting in Buffer ( Sorting occur based on key of a map function)
 2) Sorting during merging of spill files of mapper output                        3) Sorting at Reducer side None of them can happen before mapper process data

Comment: @BinaryNerd So is it guaranteed that if the input data is sorted then the  mapper will get sorted data? Or will the data be distributed in a random order to the mappers?